# Why is Enderman not attacking while in water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on survival mode, and I looked into the eyes of an Enderman while in the water, and it *did* attack, but after a while it stopped and then just began to follow me. Why did it do this?

Answer (score 5):

According to [the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman), Endermen become neutral once damaged by water or lava.

> Endermen will continue chasing a player until they are either killed, sustain several hits, or become distracted by exterior elements like rain, fire, or sun; they are likely to teleport away to underground locations, such as caves and mineshafts, at day break.

Comment: I actually didn't know how intelligent Endermen are until I read the page on the wiki. I knew they became neutral once touching lava or water, but they also try to escape if they have low health or its daytime, preferring the dark caves.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Enderman cannot teleport into water or into thin air with no blocks. As long as there are no blocks around, or on top the water the Enderman should not be able to follow you or teleport to a block near you.

Here is a question that can help answer some of your questions in further detail that was posted on the Minecraft forums page [(Link)](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/survival-mode/263893-what-can-enderman-not-teleport-on-top-of)

Comment: Well here's the thing, i was in water when it attacked but after it raged for a bit it calmed down and then afterwards when i was on land and it could clearly attack me if it wanted to, it didn't. I stared into its eyes over and over again and all it did was stare back at me and if i moved it would follow. Teleporting away away at times and then back to my side once again. It stayed with me for about 4 days before it left me and never came back. Is that even normal?

Comment: Nope, that is completely abnormal.  I have no way to explain it through facts and can only sum it up to a crazy coincidence!

Comment: Considering that Endermen are hurt by water... it sounds like a bug

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you from my own experiences that Endermen don't like water or lava at all... They will follow you until you're dead, very damaged, or it starts to rain. What I mean is that it will get damaged when it touches water so it disappears if it "falls" in the water before he ends up there.